# Entity Framework times out but query from profiler executes within milliseconds

Tags: c#, entity-framework

The following code times out after 60 seconds. It is supposed to return 10K rows for read-only purposes:

```
using (var db = new TUdvEntities(_connectionString))
{
    try
    {
        db.Set<TEjendom>().AsNoTracking();
        db.Set<TEjd_ESR>().AsNoTracking();
        db.Set<TMat>().AsNoTracking();

        IQueryable<TEjendom> query = db.TEjendom;

        foreach (var propertyId in propertiesInProgress)
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.EjdId != propertyId);
        }

        var description = propertyState.GetDescription();

        var resultListTmp = query.Where(x => x.EjdStatus == description)
            .Include(nameof(TEjd_ESR))
            .Include(nameof(TMat))
            .Take(amount).ToList();
    ....
    }
}
```

However, the query that EF generates (which I picked up from SQL Server Profiler) executes within a millisecond.

I've tried disabling change tracking with the following command:

```
db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
```

but that didnt help.

A combination of the two Includes slows the query down, however when i remove one of them, it returns an instant result.

The SQL query:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [UnionAll1].[EjdId] AS [C1], 
    [UnionAll1].[EjdId1] AS [C2], 
    [UnionAll1].[EjdType] AS [C3], 
    [UnionAll1].[BNummer] AS [C4], 
    [UnionAll1].[TNummer] AS [C5], 
    [UnionAll1].[ANummer] AS [C6], 
    [UnionAll1].[ENummer] AS [C7], 
    [UnionAll1].[Beskrivelse] AS [C8], 
    [UnionAll1].[SBT] AS [C9], 
    [UnionAll1].[EjdStatus] AS [C10], 
    [UnionAll1].[StatusTimestamp] AS [C11], 
    [UnionAll1].[IAbo] AS [C12], 
    [UnionAll1].[AOAttempts] AS [C13], 
    [UnionAll1].[AboId] AS [C14], 
    [UnionAll1].[BFE] AS [C15], 
    [UnionAll1].[UpdateToken] AS [C16], 
    [UnionAll1].[FEJ] AS [C17], 
    [UnionAll1].[C1] AS [C18], 
    [UnionAll1].[ESRId] AS [C19], 
    [UnionAll1].[EjdId2] AS [C20], 
    [UnionAll1].[Passiv] AS [C21], 
    [UnionAll1].[EjdId3] AS [C22], 
    [UnionAll1].[C2] AS [C23], 
    [UnionAll1].[C3] AS [C24], 
    [UnionAll1].[C4] AS [C25], 
    [UnionAll1].[C5] AS [C26]
    FROM  (SELECT 
        CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[ESRId] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1], 
        [Limit1].[EjdId] AS [EjdId], 
        [Limit1].[EjdId] AS [EjdId1], 
        [Limit1].[EjdType] AS [EjdType], 
        [Limit1].[BNummer] AS [BNummer], 
        [Limit1].[TNummer] AS [TNummer], 
        [Limit1].[ANummer] AS [ANummer], 
        [Limit1].[ENummer] AS [ENummer], 
        [Limit1].[Beskrivelse] AS [Beskrivelse], 
        [Limit1].[SBT] AS [SBT], 
        [Limit1].[EjdStatus] AS [EjdStatus], 
        [Limit1].[StatusTimestamp] AS [StatusTimestamp], 
        [Limit1].[IAbo] AS [IAbo], 
        [Limit1].[AOAttempts] AS [AOAttempts], 
        [Limit1].[AboId] AS [AboId], 
        [Limit1].[BFE] AS [BFE], 
        [Limit1].[UpdateToken] AS [UpdateToken], 
        [Limit1].[FEJ] AS [FEJ], 
        [Extent2].[ESRId] AS [ESRId], 
        [Extent2].[EjdId] AS [EjdId2], 
        [Extent2].[Passiv] AS [Passiv], 
        [Extent2].[EjdId] AS [EjdId3], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C2], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C3], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C4], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C5]
        FROM   (SELECT TOP (10416) 
            [Extent1].[EjdId] AS [EjdId], 
            [Extent1].[EjdType] AS [EjdType], 
            [Extent1].[BNummer] AS [BNummer], 
            [Extent1].[TNummer] AS [TNummer], 
            [Extent1].[ANummer] AS [ANummer], 
            [Extent1].[ENummer] AS [ENummer], 
            [Extent1].[Beskrivelse] AS [Beskrivelse], 
            [Extent1].[SBT] AS [SBT], 
            [Extent1].[EjdStatus] AS [EjdStatus], 
            [Extent1].[StatusTimestamp] AS [StatusTimestamp], 
            [Extent1].[IAbo] AS [IAbo], 
            [Extent1].[AOAttempts] AS [AOAttempts], 
            [Extent1].[AboId] AS [AboId], 
            [Extent1].[BFE] AS [BFE], 
            [Extent1].[UpdateToken] AS [UpdateToken], 
            [Extent1].[FEJ] AS [FEJ]
            FROM [dbo].[TEjendom] AS [Extent1]
            WHERE ([Extent1].[EjdStatus] = @p__linq__0) OR (([Extent1].[EjdStatus] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL)) ) AS [Limit1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[TEjd_ESR] AS [Extent2] ON [Limit1].[EjdId] = [Extent2].[EjdId]
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 
        2 AS [C1], 
        [Limit2].[EjdId] AS [EjdId], 
        [Limit2].[EjdId] AS [EjdId1], 
        [Limit2].[EjdType] AS [EjdType], 
        [Limit2].[BNummer] AS [BNummer], 
        [Limit2].[TNummer] AS [TNummer], 
        [Limit2].[ANummer] AS [ANummer], 
        [Limit2].[ENummer] AS [ENummer], 
        [Limit2].[Beskrivelse] AS [Beskrivelse], 
        [Limit2].[SBT] AS [SBT], 
        [Limit2].[EjdStatus] AS [EjdStatus], 
        [Limit2].[StatusTimestamp] AS [StatusTimestamp], 
        [Limit2].[IAbo] AS [IAbo], 
        [Limit2].[AOAttempts] AS [AOAttempts], 
        [Limit2].[AboId] AS [AboId], 
        [Limit2].[BFE] AS [BFE], 
        [Limit2].[UpdateToken] AS [UpdateToken], 
        [Limit2].[FEJ] AS [FEJ], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C2], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C3], 
        CAST(NULL AS bit) AS [C4], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C5], 
        [Extent4].[EjdId] AS [EjdId2], 
        [Extent4].[LeKode] AS [LeKode], 
        [Extent4].[MatNummer] AS [MatNummer], 
        [Extent4].[EjdId] AS [EjdId3]
        FROM   (SELECT TOP (10416) 
            [Extent3].[EjdId] AS [EjdId], 
            [Extent3].[EjdType] AS [EjdType], 
            [Extent3].[BNummer] AS [BNummer], 
            [Extent3].[TNummer] AS [TNummer], 
            [Extent3].[ANummer] AS [ANummer], 
            [Extent3].[ENummer] AS [ENummer], 
            [Extent3].[Beskrivelse] AS [Beskrivelse], 
            [Extent3].[SBT] AS [SBT], 
            [Extent3].[EjdStatus] AS [EjdStatus], 
            [Extent3].[StatusTimestamp] AS [StatusTimestamp], 
            [Extent3].[IAbo] AS [IAbo], 
            [Extent3].[AOAttempts] AS [AOAttempts], 
            [Extent3].[AboId] AS [AboId], 
            [Extent3].[BFE] AS [BFE], 
            [Extent3].[UpdateToken] AS [UpdateToken], 
            [Extent3].[FEJ] AS [FEJ]
            FROM [dbo].[TEjendom] AS [Extent3]
            WHERE ([Extent3].[EjdStatus] = @p__linq__0) OR (([Extent3].[EjdStatus] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL)) ) AS [Limit2]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[TMat] AS [Extent4] ON [Limit2].[EjdId] = [Extent4].[EjdId]) AS [UnionAll1]
    ORDER BY [UnionAll1].[EjdId1] ASC, [UnionAll1].[C1] ASC',N'@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000)',@p__linq__0=N'HentData'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The first 3 `AsNoTracking()` calls have no any affect - you have to use the result of the call. Try putting `AsNoTracking()` here: `IQueryable<TinglysEjendom> query = db.TEjendom.AsNoTracking();`

Comment: I tried that, makes no difference :/ Remvoing the includes makes it a whole lot faster. Lazy loading TEjd_ESR and TMat on 10K rows would not help though.

Comment: Could you also post the query?

Comment: @bubi I have posted it now

Comment: First thought is that you're running into a parameter sniffing type of issue. A common symptom is a query runs slow via code but fast via SSMS

Comment: Seen it. Not so ugly query. The timeout is on the ToList of the query or is on a UI (ASP/MVC)? Also, to understand if the problem is materialization process or the query, you could try to remove the ToList and iterate through the IQueryable. This use a datareader during iteration so if you have the first record immediately the issue could be related to materialization process not to the query.

Comment: Does the second call via code timeout? Might it be that the second execution is fast just because it is executed the second time (some data is cached by SQL)?  Run the SQL profiler before you execute your code. Does this query still execute in ms?

Comment: try to execute the execution plan and encode the required indexes on the tables to support the query

Comment: @bubi The timeout is on the ToList method. I analyzed the DB further. The DB sends the data back fast and locks all rows until EF tells it that it has finished. However EF does not tell it that it has finished before the timeout. I suspect the error is in the "materialization process". Changing the Take amount to something lower fixes the issue for now. Also, right now, when I query the DB with an off Take amount like 10416 it times out, but returns an instant result when the amount is 12000. Might be because it has cached something.

Comment: @Kenci You are aware that running the query (which you expect 10K result records from) in SSMS only shows you the first 100 result records? You have to scroll down to get the next 100, and so forth. You can't compare execution times like that.

Comment: @Maarten are you sure about that? I just executed the query and it shows 24K rows (no loading when I scroll down) even though the statement uses TOP 10416 (I dont know how EF filters it). Anyway the profiler also says the query is executed fast.

Comment: @Kenci Ok, could be. My experiences were different, but I do not remember which version of SSMS that was.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Allan S. Hansen's comment regarding parameter sniffing.

You query in part has `WHERE ([Extent1].[EjdStatus] = @p__linq__0)`  and the `@p__linq__0` parameter is passed in as `nvarchar(4000)` in the query at the end:

ORDER BY [UnionAll1].[EjdId1] ASC, [UnionAll1].[C1] ASC',N'@p__linq__0 **nvarchar(4000)**',@p__linq__0=N'HentData'

I'm guessing that the EjdStatus column is not defined as nvarchar(4000) in the database.  I believe that this is making the database choose the wrong execution plan or index.  We experienced this issue and what we did was to make sure that the EF query used the correct data types and that helped a lot.

We did this by calling the `HasDataType` method in the `OnModelCreating` override in our data context:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyClass>().Property(a => a.EjdStatus).HasColumnType("VARCHAR");

    //other code here
}
```

This caused EF to use the correct datatype in the query it generates which allowed Sql to pick the appropriate execution plan.